# Is there a nicer alternative to ".map(|x| *x)" before ".collect()"?

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

In the following snippet:

```
let b: Vec<usize> = a.iter().filter(|x| **x > 5).map(|x| *x).collect();
```

Is there a nicer way to make `b` be a vector of values rather than references? (instead of `.map(|x| *x)`)

Is there something like:

```
fn iter_values<T : Copy>(c: &Vec<T>) -> std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<T>, fn(&T) -> T> {
    c.iter().map(|x| *x)
}
```

That can be used like so:

```
let b: Vec<usize> = iter_values(&a).filter(|x| *x > 5).collect();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`.copied`**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied):

```
let b: Vec<usize> = a.iter().copied().filter(|x| *x > 5).collect();
```

Alternatively you can use [**`.cloned`**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) which works for any type that implements `Clone`, but beware that this might induce a non-trivial cost to turn references into  objects by cloning them.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using `copied()` or `cloned()`, you may be able to consume the source container by using [`into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) instead of `iter()`:

```
let b: Vec<usize> = a.into_iter().filter(|x| *x > 5).collect();
```

You can use this if you don't need the original container after this point in the code.